# Express adds first part of URL to injections if you use 2 level URLs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am using Node.js + Express.

When you have 1-level URL like:

```
/estonia
```

All of the scripts and styles are loaded correctly but if you have a 2-level URL like:

```
/estonia/tallinn
```

Scripts and styles injections are failing because it adds `/estonia` to the path:

Before: http://localhost:5050/js/config.js
After: http://localhost:5050/estonia/js/config.js

Here is my `routes.js` file:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    var url = req.url.slice(1);
    var urlParamsArray = url.split("/");
    if ( countries[urlParamsArray[0]] && (urlParamsArray.length===1 || cities[urlParamsArray[1]]) ) {
        res.sendFile(config.ROOT_PATH +'/'+ config.PUBLIC_PATH+'/index.html');
    } else {
        res.status(404).sendFile(config.ROOT_PATH + '/'+ config.PUBLIC_PATH+'/404.html');
    }
});
```

Here is my `express.js` file:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(session({secret:config.EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET}));
app.use(favicon(config.ROOT_PATH+'/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(express.static(config.ROOT_PATH+"/"+config.PUBLIC_PATH));
```

**How can I fix that?**

Comment: please add ejs page source code

Comment: I believe if you remove the entire `app.get('*', fn);` in your `routes.js` file it should start working as it should, since you've already set the static directory with `app.use(express.static(config.ROOT_PATH+"/"+config.PUBLIC_PATH));`

Comment: and how should express understand that it has to load index.html if the URL is `/estonia/tallinn`; this works only when you have `/` or direct path `js/config.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<base href="/">` to `<head>` section of your templates.